# how to convert json?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I want to convert firstname and lastname to json format.

```
@RestController
public class studentsController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/students", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE } )
    @ResponseBody
    public String getWhoami(@RequestParam String firstname, @RequestParam String lastname ) {
        return "firstname:" + firstname + " lastname: " + lastname;
    }
}
```

How can I convert like these format;

```
{"firstname": "value1", "lastname": "value2"}
```

I tried to jackson but I couldn't.

Comment: The Spring official guide [Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) has a good demonstration for this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create json manually.
Create a class like:

```java
class Student {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    
    public Student(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname  =lastname;
    }
    // getters and setter 
}
```

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/students", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE } )
    @ResponseBody
    public Student getWhoami(@RequestParam String firstname, @RequestParam String lastname ) {
        return new Student(firstname, lastname);
    }
```

You object will be converted to json automatically.

Comment: call this api. using postman or any browser. This will word.

Comment: You don't have to manually convert it to json.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the jackson like this?

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind

add in your class an instance like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

```
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

try function from the instance like this:

```
String jsonstr = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
```

Lets say you already have the jackson library in your project (the jar file)

here's  sample class:

```
public class SampleClass{
      private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

      public String sampleMethodToJSONString(Student student){
          return mapper.writeValueAsString(student);
      }

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the return data type to use Map<String, String> instead of String or use ResponseBody<?>